# ASP.NET sending data to VIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I start studying asp.net MVC and I am confused about sending data to VIEW. I have one class Dispatch:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Logistic.Models
{
    public class Dispatch
    {
        public int DispatchId { get; set; }
        public int TrackingId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int RecipientId { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Delivered { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Another class City:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Logistic.Models
{
    public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A class Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Logistic.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

From my class Dispatch, CustomerId and RecipientId will be related to the class Client; CityId related to City.

I create my context class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Logistic.Models
{
    public class LogisticContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Dispatch> Dispatches { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
using Logistic.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Logistic.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private LogisticContext db = new LogisticContext();

        public ActionResult Dispatch()
        {
            var dispatches = db.Dispatches.ToList();

            return View(dispatches);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in my View class I do not know how to display the Customer Name, Recipient Name, and City Name. I only can display the CustomerId, RecipientId, and CityId.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Logistic.Models.Dispatch>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dispatch";
}

<h2>Dispatch</h2>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <h2></h2>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any relationships between these entities? If so, you could likely just use an `Include()` to populate the specific related entities that you need (e.g. `db.Dispatches.Include("Cities").ToList()`). This assumes that you have foreign keys that can be used to match up the relationships.

Comment: you also can use a View model which is solely responsible for your view here. Then you populate whatever data you need to display from your backend into your view model before you pass your view model to the view.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have relationships in place...**

If you already have defined relationships between these properties, you can generally use the `Include()` method to pull related entities in as seen below :

```
// Pull all of the dispatches and their related cities
var dispatchesWithCities = db.Dispatches.Include("Cities")
                                        .ToList();
```

If you do this and have the proper relationships, you would then be able to iterate through and access the `item.City.Name`, however it doesn't look like that is the case in your current scenario.

**Without relationships...**

If you don't have these "hard" relationships in place, you can still perform a few database queries to pull the properties you need and construct a ViewModel, but it wouldn't be pretty with so many results :

```
public class DispatchViewModel
{
      public Dispatch Dispatch { get; set; }
      public City City { get; set; }
      public Client Client { get; set; }
      public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

And then use each of your individual Dispatch objects and map them to their related properties :

```
// Build your Dispatches with related information
var dispatchModels = db.Dispatches.AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select(d => new DispatchViewModel()
                                  {
                                      Dispatch = d,
                                      City = db.Cities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CityId == d.CityId),
                                      Client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientId == d.CustomerId),
                                      ...
                                  });
```

At this point you can simply iterate through the collection and output them by referencing the iterator in the loop :

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <h2>@item.Dispatch.DispatchId</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <b>City</b>: @item.City.Name
           <!-- Other stuff here -->
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Which is correct with relationship or without relationship? How can I create relationship between these classes?

Comment: @Apprentice123456 If your objects are related in the conceptual sense, then the database should reflect that.

Comment: I tried to create a relationship, but I am getting the following error:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

Line 14:     <h2>City : @item.City.Name</h2> <br />

Answer (score 0):

You can use view model approach to send data from mutliple views to controller.  Here is an example: 
http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/